# How to use ScriptingConfig.xml in DPM

Tags: scdpm

I try to find out how to get Pre-backup and Post-backup scripts for DPM to work in my enviroment, via scriptconfig.xml.

I use System Center 2019 DPM version 10.19.577.0

I have a hyper-v cluster of 3 servers, where on each server about 10 vms are running. For the vm who is running oracle i want run a pre backup script so the oracle database is clossed before i make a backup. I have a protection group with only that oracle vm in it and want to use scriptingconfig.xml when that protection group runs to run a batch file to stop the database.

I made a test-begin.cmd and test-eind.cmd script that only echo the current date and time to a txt-file and placed it at a test dir on the vm.

I made a protection group named ernst01 and selected only the c-drive of server01.

When i do a "perform a consistency check" it failes with the message "The configuration of the pre-backup script or the post-backup script XML for volume c:\ is incorrect. (ID 30193: Details internal error code: 0x809909F4)". But i do not know what the xml error means.

The scriptingconfig.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScriptConfiguration xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
 xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
 xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/dls/ScriptingConfig.xsd">
    <DatasourceScriptConfig DataSourceName="C:">
        <PreBackupScript>c:\test\test-begin.cmd </PreBackupScript>
        <PostBackupScript>c:\test\test-eind.cmd </PostBackupScript>
        <TimeOut>30<\TimeOut>
    </DatasourceScriptConfig>
</ScriptConfiguration>
```

the batch file looks like this:

```
set now=%date:~-4%%date:~7,2%%date:~4,2%-%time%

echo begin gelukt %now% >>c:\test\test.log
```

I tried changing the c: into c:\ and c with and without various quotes but no change in the error. NOTE: also if i change DatasourceName to pipotheclown it keep giving the error. So i think this line has the error.

I tried using " and ' and none around the c:\test....cmd. But nothing what i do seems to change the error.

NOTE: When i completly remove the DatasourceScriptConfig then the "perform consistancy check" runs without errors

Hope someone can help me with what i do wrong.